# Join multiple rasters at specific locations, when the number of rasters is variable

Tags: r, imagemagick, raster

Given "n" rasters, each exactly 100x100 px, I want to combine them all in a single plot such that there are exactly 4 images per row. For n > 4, a new row should be created and so on. Thus, the dimensions of the empty plot created will be fixed along the x-axis, but the y-axis will depend on the number of rasters. I used image_montage() function from "magick" package to generate montages as follows:

```
mag_montage <- list()
for(ii in 1:n){
filelist_crop <- list.files()[grep(".png",list.files())]  
mag_montagetemp <- image_read(filelist_crop)
mag_montage[[ii]] <- image_montage(mag_montagetemp)
}
```

But I can't control the specific position of each individual file within the file montage this way. Knowing the locations is very crucial, as I need to pick certain xy coordinates (using "locator") from the combined rasters for some downstream processing. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: with "join" you mean combine them in a single plot?

Comment: Yes. I will update my question to make it clearer.

Comment: I don't know `R` but on the command line, if you want your montage 4 images wide you would do `montage -tile 4x ...` or if you wanted it 3 images tall you would do `montage -tile x3 ...` Maybe you can adapt.

Comment: You can simply +-append them in Imagemagick or use +-smush if you want to add spacing. Or better, just use -layers merge all the images onto your background with specific page offsets. It will expand the background as needed to hold your images. See for example, https://imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/

Comment: I needed it done in R. Its a part of a much larger utility function that extends beyond just image processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can plot all the rasters inside the list `rlist` into one plot with 4 columns:

```
library(raster)

n <- 26

rlist <- lapply(1:n,function(x) raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")))

par(mfrow=c(ceiling(n/4),4))

for (ii in 1:length(rlist)){

  plot(rlist[[ii]])

## additional options for plot to omit legend and box
#bty="n", box=FALSE, axes=F, legend=F

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the prompt solution Val. This works for the most part, except one glitch. The resultant final plot (with multiple rasters) is used by the next function in my pipeline which is graphics::locator. Locator captures xy coordinates for all mouse clicks, as expected, but now it marks the location only on the last raster (i.e. n = 26th in the example above). I understand why this might happen, but would you know of a work-around this problem?

Comment: Using `locator`, I'm receiving xy coordinates for each click within the coordinate system of the plot. I still don't quite understand what your ultimate goal is, but in this case the coordinates won't correspond to the spatial coordinates of the raster dataset

Comment: The individual rasters are all cropped from a single original image. I can find the spatial coordinates of the original raster data using a transformation since the midpoint of each individual raster corresponds to a known location on the original image. Recieving the xy coordinates using locator was not an issue, that works for me too. The "marking" it using locator(type = "p") is not working.

Comment: Looks like only the last plot stays active for points to be added. I've tried a couple of things, but unfortunately nothing really worked. I found [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-September/057184.html) which might be helpful, without having gone through it. Otherwise, maybe you can do without the markings? Or find a way to infer the subplot from each coordinate pair and "re-activate" it while adding the points.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am thinking. Thanks a lot though. You've been super helpful. Will update the response here if I figure out a work-around.

Comment: Glad i could help a bit at least!

Comment: Just saw the reference you shared. Might be just what I was looking for. The code is a little messy, but I'll take it. Thanks a lot.